# JNI converting jstring to char *

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have passed a URL string from Java to C code as `jstring` data type through the use of JNI. And my library method needs a `char *` as url.

How can I convert `jstring` in `char *` ?

P.S.: Is there any advantage of using jcharArray in C? (i.e. Passing `char []` instead of string in native method)

Comment: Have you considered consulting the documentation?

Answer (score 242, accepted):

Here's a a couple of useful link that I found when I started with JNI

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html

concerning your problem you can use this

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ClassName_MethodName(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring javaString)   
{
   const char *nativeString = env->GetStringUTFChars(javaString, 0);

   // use your string

   env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(javaString, nativeString);
}
```

Comment: is it necessary to keep `nativeString` constant?

Comment: if you check the second link, the prototype of the function GetStringUTFChars is:

const jbyte* GetStringUTFChars(JNIEnv *env, jstring string, 
jboolean *isCopy); so you don't really have a choise

Comment: no problems, I'm getting to the end of my project with JNI but I know how much I struggled to start with

Comment: I think it's worth noting that the technique outlined here (and on the Wikipedia page) uses modified UTF-8 encoding, which may not work in all situations. See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/jni.html#UTF_8_and_UTF_16_strings

Comment: I think this approach works only in the case when all characters are encoded with 1 byte. But an UTF8 string can have characters encoded with 2 and 4 bytes too.

Comment: Thanks, that work but interestingly const char* can not convert into char* :).

Comment: @CoDe Technically, it could with some magic, but that is best avoided; it is probably declared `const` for a reason. The correct response to your problem is to `strcpy` from the `const char*` into a `char*`. That should provide you with the mutable `char*` that you want.

Comment: I tried your method. The string has been converted to char* but when I log it, it shows some raw, random characters.

Answer (score 53):

Thanks Jason Rogers's answer first.

In **Android** && **cpp** should be this:

```
const char *nativeString = env->GetStringUTFChars(javaString, nullptr);

// use your string

env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(javaString, nativeString);
```

Can fix this errors:

1.error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'JNIEnv {aka _JNIEnv}'

2.error: no matching function for call to '_JNIEnv::GetStringUTFChars(JNIEnv*&, _jstring*&, bool)'

3.error: no matching function for call to '_JNIEnv::ReleaseStringUTFChars(JNIEnv*&, _jstring*&, char const*&)'

4.add "env->DeleteLocalRef(nativeString);" at end.

Comment: You need to have (*env)-> instead of env->

Comment: You only need `(*env)->` if you are using C, not C++.

Comment: how to convert string to sha256 i am unable to do this pls help new in ndk android