# JNI parse jstring or char* without std in android/java

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

What is the way to parse a given jstring without std?

I am in android, and cannot fint a way to use string functions. Is it not available?

I d like something similar then: .replaceAll, .split, .startWith, or StringTokenizer, etc in Java.

> "jni/hello-jni.cpp:207: error: 'string' in namespace 'std' does not
>   name a type"

Thanks, 
Leslie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that by "without std" you mean without C++ and `std::string` in particular. In that case you can use any standard [C string functions](http://www.edcc.edu/faculty/paul.bladek/c_string_functions.htm) or throw in your own as you feel need. For conversion from `jstring` to `const char *` you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181934/jni-converting-jstring-to-char).