# Converting native type to jni type

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface, native

Look question [Parameter passing in native a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990929/parameter-passing-in-native-a-method).
What to do if I want to write a native method Traverser (String path), which returns a value? How do I convert a long int type in C in Java type that returns a native method Traverser (String path)? For example how to transform long int to jlong?
If I want to write a method

```
public native long Traverser (String path),
```

whether will be correct this code

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_ParallelIndexation_Traverser(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jstring path) 
{ 
    long int result;
    const jbyte* path2 = env->GetStringUTFChars(path, nullptr); 
    if (path2 == nullptr) 
        return; 

    result=Traverser(path2); 

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(path, path2); 
    return result;
}
```

?

Or is it necessary to convert

```
long int result
```

to

```
jlong?
```

And whether Java_ParallelIndexation_Traverser is possible instead of

```
long int result;
```

to declare

```
jlong result;
```

?

Comment: what's the point of asking the same question again on the same forum when your previous one is still open?

Comment: @Arham Unless you don't see distinction in questions (look millimoose comments on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990929/parameter-passing-in-native-a-method - Don't move the goalposts. If your original question was answered, accept an answer and ask additional questions separately, instead of expanding the scope of one question forever)?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?