# Writing jstring to logcat in JNI function

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I'm trying to debug my `JNI` function, and in doing so I wish to display the incoming `jstring` argument to `logcat` to verify its correctness.

I've tried the following code to do so, but it keeps crashing out.

```
LOGD(myStringArg);
```

where `myStringArg` is declared as a `jstring`.

If I declare and define another `jstring` within my `JNI` function and `LOGD` that, it works. However, for some reason if I call `LOGD` on the `JNI` function argument it crashes. I have verified internally that the `jstring` is not null, and right before calling it in the Java function, I also check that the value is correct.

I've converted the jstring to a const char * as follows:

```
const char *charString;
charString = (const char*)(*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, myStringArg, NULL);
LOGD(charString);
```

Nothing is displayed, which means charString is empty?

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Might be duplicated with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181934/jni-converting-jstring-to-char)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to extract chars from the jstring using this method:

```
const char* getCharFromString(JNIEnv* env, jstring string){
    if(string == NULL)
        return NULL;

    return  env->GetStringUTFChars(string ,0);
}
```

This way you can print your `jstring` as `(const char*)`:

```
LOGD(getCharFromString(env, myStringArg));
```

If you still have problem printing this string, try to debug the content using using these methods:

```
int getBytesNeededByString(JNIEnv* env, jstring string){
    return env->GetStringUTFLength(string);
}

int getNumberOfCharsInString(JNIEnv* env, jstring string){
    return env->GetStringLength(string);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the `jstring` to a native `char*` or `string`. For example:

```
// Get a pointer to an array of bytes representing the string in modified UTF-8 encoding
char *str = env->GetStringUTFChars(myStringArgs, NULL);

// Now you can log str

// Inform the VM that the native code no longer needs access to str
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(myStringArg, str);
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html for more info on JNI functions.

Comment: I've converted the jstring to a const char *, updated the original post with the code. When I LOGD on the const char *, nothing comes out, it seems to be a null string.

Comment: What does `GetStringUTFLength` return for your `jstring`?

Answer (score -1):

you can try like this,

```
LOGD("String from java is %s\n",charString);
```

it is working for me.

Answer (score -1):

try this:
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "LOG_TAG", "text:%s ", charString );