# Error:(289, 23)C++ / JNI / NDK - error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'char *' with an lvalue of type 'jstring' (aka '_jstring *')

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, syntax-error

I have an error working with C++/Android (JNI) and I absolutely don't know how to fix it.. (I'm very new to C++)

> Error:(289, 23) error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'char *' with an lvalue of type 'jstring' (aka '_jstring *')

the error points at this line

```
JNIEXPORT void Java_de_meetspot_ndktest_MainActivity_LoadPlayerA(JNIEnv *javaEnvironment, jobject self, jstring audioPath, jlongArray offsetAndLength) {
    example->LoadPlayerA(audioPath, offsetAndLength);
}
```

in my class-declaration I have:

```
public: void LoadPlayerA(char *audioPath, int *params);android
```

Can someone tell me, where I it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty self explanatory.  In `example->LoadPlayerA(audioPath, offsetAndLength);` the type of `audioPath` is a `jstring` but in your `LoadPlayerA()` function the first parameter is `char *audioPath`.  The compiler does not know how to convert a `jstring` to a `char*` so you are going to have to do it yourself.

Borrowing from [Jason Rogers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440336/jason-rogers) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4181982/4342498) you can change your code to:

```
JNIEXPORT void Java_de_meetspot_ndktest_MainActivity_LoadPlayerA(JNIEnv *javaEnvironment, jobject self, jstring audioPath, jlongArray offsetAndLength)
{
    const char* audio = javaEnvironment->GetStringUTFChars(audioPath, JNI_FALSE)
    example->LoadPlayerA(audio, offsetAndLength);
    javaEnvironment->ReleaseStringUTFChars(audioPath, audio);
}
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot to include the `Release()` function.  This needs to be called when you are done with the array otherwise you will have a memory leak.

Comment: Hi .. thank you a lot.. the explenation seems legit :)) .. but now I get a other error which I dont know how to solve .. Error:(289, 40) error: member reference type 'JNIEnv' (aka '_JNIEnv') is not a pointer; maybe you meant to use '.'?

Comment: @GeneralError Opps.  looks like things changed.  I have updated the code.

Comment: hey thank you :))) .. that seems to work :)) .. is there a similar function (like GetStringUTFChars()) for jlongArray? ..  Error:(290, 33) error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'int *' with an lvalue of type 'jlongArray' (aka '_jlongArray *')

Comment: [This page](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html) has some good examples about half way down in the section 4.3  Passing Array of Primitives.  The function you would use would be GetLongArrayElements()